# kendo-react-ui "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayName')"

Tags: kendo-react-ui

I am using Kendo-react library in my React project.
I am try to render a table with the **Grid** component
but in the browser I don't see anything and in the console i get error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayName')".
Has anyone encountered this error?

this is the code:

```
<Grid
    // total={productsExample.length}
    // data={orderBy(productsExample, sort)}
    // sortable={true}
    // sort={sort}
    // onSortChange={columnSort}
>
    <GridColumn className="AAAAAAA" title="some title" field="SubmittingID" width='120px' />
    <GridColumn title="RequestID" field="RequestID" />
    <GridColumn title="Address" field="AddressName" />
    <GridColumn title="Rounds Number" field="RoundsNumber" />
    <GridColumn title="Last Delivery Date" field="LastDeliveryDate" /> {/* check sort by dates - not sorting  */}
    <GridColumn title="Date Of Department Notes" field="DateOfDepartmentNotes" /> {/* check sort by dates - not sorting  */}
    <GridColumn title="Notes" field="Notes" />
    <GridColumn title="Responsible" field="Responsible" />
</Grid>
```

and screenshot is here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWtK7.png)

and this what i am see in the console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unn3r.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of research,
I debug the code in the console and i see something weird.
I have 8 celles and instade of 8 cells i see 10 and 2 of them was empty quotes,
and suddenly i realized that is the 2 lines that i put in comment,
so i removed them and i got the table.
Another thing that i understood if i put the comments in new line and i got the table.
Probably if the comments are in the same line of some cell
the compiler think that the comments are part of the cell and try to render them